# How to model ressources in a Java Project UML?

Tags: java, uml

My Supervisor asked me to search or model a Java Project in UML. Not a specific Project, but a more general apporach like how the Java language works. I sticked to the JLS whil creating the model and came to this result: 
[UML diagram of a Java project][1] 
Now he wants me to include ressources like css files or other Java-related files, that could be used in a Java project. How do I do that? My first idea was to add an Aggregation to project, but the problem with that is, a ressource could exist without a project. 
I couldn't find anything in the web about modeling a Java project in UML, that suprised me since doing that would be an obvious task before writing f.e. an IDE. 
Any ideas about the model are very much welcome. I published the model, together with the visual paradigm file on git hub, in case somebody needs that: [UML Diagram for Java Projects](https://github.com/thosob/Java-project-as-UML-class-diagramm-and-ER-diagramm.git)

Edit: 
[UML diagram of a Java project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1YrW.jpg)

Thank you very much. I worked in all the comments. :)

Comment: A `Resource` would be a subclass of `File` in your diagram, wouldn't it?

Comment: Most glaring to me: convert all your lists into associations with multiplicity and association-end property names. Make sure association ends are named as properties.

Comment: Thank you guys! I'll post my updated uml. I tried to express the lists with associations. I know hope multiple relations between two classes are okay :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

[image]

A class uses a resource which can be a CSS or other stuff. A resource is a file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared aggregation.

Neither shared nor composite aggregation require the aggregated element to exist only as a part of a whole (you can use multiplicity with a zero possible on a whole end of this relationship). Moreover shared aggregation means that the same element can be in relationship with many different elements, so resource is a good example for that.

You can also use simple (direct) association.